# How can i figure out instruction pointer address in the certain part of my java code?

Tags: java, jvm, ida

I'm just trying to get a memory trace generated by Java code(JVM) using pin tool(pinatrace). But every result of the microbenchmarks I try to figure out the traces shows almost same graphs, and even utilizing processbuilder inside Java code gives no remarkable results at least in comparing among different microbenchmarks. I realized that I should extract the substantive part(excluding useless part for analysis, like initializing, accessing to JVM in the middle of main code....) of the code to figure out what is going wrong.

Because the instruction pointer is sent to pinatrace at the moment it detects memory access, I thought getting the instruction pointer of substantive part and set the parameter with those information would work. But Finding the way(or the tool) for this job is driving me crazy, since Java is not a familiar field to me....

I've already tried IDA pro, but it only says The input file format is wrong, when I input .class file. and setting .java file as input shows me just binary code which seems like the text file is converted to binary things and nothing. Tried to install IDAjava addon but also does not work....... Is there any easy method to get the IP instead? what I just want to know is IP from java code..

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Luring you to the NetBeans IDE with its profiling will not do I guess? It would at least provide a comparison.

Comment: Sorry my question was quite confusing. I just want to get the IP generated by my java code.. thx!

Comment: I suggest trying JMH with perfasm.  This can show you which assembly instructions are taking the most time and is supported for Java 6+